# std::merge using 2 mmaped arrays?

Tags: c++, c, unix, stl, mmap

I'm mmaping two text files with an integer written on each line.
I read them from the drive and I wanted to do a sorted merge on them.
The two input files "1piece0" and "1piece1" have a list of sorted integers.
The output file does have the size as the two files combined, but not that many integers.
Problem: The two input files have 25430000 lines, while the output file should have 50860000 lines but it has only has 17259463 lines.
This is my current code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <algorithm>

#define FILESIZE 25430000 * sizeof(int)
#define FILE0 279288034
#define FILE1 279287226
int main()
{
    int i;
    int fd;
    int fd2;
    int fd3;
    int result;
    int *map;
    int *map2;
    int *map3;

    fd3 = open( "file.out", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0755);
    if ( fd3 == -1 ) {
        perror("Error opening file for writing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    result = lseek(fd3, FILE0 + FILE1 - 1, SEEK_SET );
    if(result == -1) {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error calling lseek\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    result = write(fd3,"",1);
    if( result != 1 ) {
        close(fd3);
        perror("error writing last byte");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    map3 =(int *) mmap(0, FILE0 + FILE1, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd3, 0);
    if( map == MAP_FAILED ) {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error mmapinG fd3");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    fd = open( "1piece0", O_RDONLY );
    if( fd == -1 ) {
        perror("Error opening file for writing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    map = (int *)mmap(0, FILE0, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0 );
    if( map == MAP_FAILED ) {
        close(fd);
        perror("error mapping file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fd2 = open( "1piece1", O_RDONLY );
    if( fd2 == -1 ) {
        perror("Error opening file for writing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    map2 = (int *)mmap(0, FILE1, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd2, 0 );
    if( map == MAP_FAILED ) {
        close(fd2);
        perror("error mapping file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

//  while(1);
    std::merge( map, map + 25430000, map2, map2 + 25430000, map3 );

    if(munmap(map, FILE0 ) == -1 ) {
        perror("error unmapping map");
    }
    close(fd);

    if(munmap(map3, FILE0 + FILE1 ) == -1 ) {
        perror("error unmapping map3");
    }
    close(fd3);

    if(munmap(map2, FILE1 ) == -1 ) {
        perror("error unmapping map2");
    }
    close(fd2);

    return 0;
}
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Update: By lines I mean an integer number and then a newline character.

Comment: Tell us more about what is going wrong.

Comment: @Jens - Well The files are in form of integer and then a newline character.
So I wanted to sorted merge them. I think I can't mmap them.
The exact problem is that there don't appear to be enough lines in the output file.

Comment: The if condition next to map2 and map3 shouldn't they be checking against map2 and map3, instead of map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot treat text lines as binary blobs to be manipulated as int pointers.

You can treat text files as text to be [extracted and used](http://codepad.org/5PfIpzYM):

```
void merge_ints(std::istream &a_in, std::istream &b_in, std::ostream &out) {
  int a, b;
  std::istream *remaining = 0;
  if (!(a_in >> a)) {
    remaining = &b_in;
  }
  else if (!(b_in >> b)) {
    out << a << '\n';
    remaining = &a_in;
  }
  else while (a_in && b_in) {
    if (a < b) {
      out << a << '\n';
      if (!(a_in >> a)) {
        out << b << '\n';
        remaining = &b_in;
      }
    }
    else {
      out << b << '\n';
      if (!(b_in >> b)) {
        out << a << '\n';
        remaining = &a_in;
      }
    }
  }
  for (int x; *remaining >> x;) {
    out << x << '\n';
  }
}
```

[Taking advantage of std::merge](http://codepad.org/dqZcXt5U):

```
void merge_ints(std::istream &a, std::istream &b, std::ostream &out) {
  typedef std::istream_iterator<int> In;
  std::merge(In(a), In(), In(b), In(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(out, "\n"));
}

int main() {
  stringstream a ("1\n3\n5\n"), b ("2\n4\n6\n7\n"), out;
  merge_ints(a, b, out);
  cout << out.str();
}
```

Comment: The primary reason I don't want to use streams is they are too slow.
I wanted the program to be as fast as possible.
I only have a 100mb of main memory so I wanted to mmap them, but I think I will have to write the code to store them in chunks on memory and perform a merge..
C File I/O is faster isn't it? Shouldn't I use that?

Comment: @Skkard: Why don't you test it?  Using the scanf-family is fine too.  The main point is if you have text data, you cannot treat it as non-text ("binary") data.

Comment: It is faster, but not as much as I had hoped.
Thanks for clearing things up :).

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "lines"?

When you memory map it treats the data like it is memory and here you are reading it like an array of ints. Therefore the inputs must be in native binary format (i.e. with the bytes stored in the same way, same size and same endianness), and 25430000 is the number of ints you are reading in from each collection.

Is that how your inputs are stored?

There are a lot of "magic numbers" here.

Comment: It is a text file. Should I convert it to a binary file?
How do I do that?

Comment: If you to do it this way you need to, but you can use streams to read the text. The easiest way is just to use istream_iterator<int> on the open file handle (ifstream) as your input iterator type.